# Understanding electric conduction in tight binding model

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, conductors, tight-binding, bloch-oscillation

Let's consider a system of free electrons moving in a one dimensional lattice with dispersion $\varepsilon(k) = -2t\cos{ka}$, ($a$ is the lattice spacing and $t$ the hopping amplitude). Let's now superimpose a uniform force $F$ to the system, so that the Hamiltonian reads
$$
H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 + V(x) - Fx,
$$
$V(x)$ being the periodic lattice potential. I know that the external force induces Bloch oscillations of the electrons, which are spatial oscillations of amplitude $\propto t/F$ and frequency $\propto F$.

However, I would naively expect that, at least in the limit $F\gg t$, the electrons should not oscillate, but instead they should follow the foce and accelerate uniformly. This idea is suggested by the fact that we typically refer to the system with $F=0$ as a "metal", so an external force should drag the electrons.
In other words, I find the Bloch oscillation very counter-intuitive; moreover it seems like this model does not explain the expected conduction properties of electrons.

Can anyone tell me how the intuitive classical behavior of an acceleration resulting from the external force is recovered in this formalism?

Comment: This is actually the wrong way to go about it. This additional term causes every quantum state to become unbound because the asymptotic behaviour is now all wrong. Problems with this is so severe that there is just no way to obtain the correct, wanted, behaviour. Instead, the smart way to obtain conduction, is to apply the Modern Theory of Polarisation: convert the constant E field, that is your F, into a time derivative of the vector potential A, and take the quasistatic long time limit. Then you can extract dielectric and conduction properties beautifully.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that changing the picture to the one with minimally coupled momentum $p-A(t)$ makes the problem more tractable, but I don't see how this explains conductivity. Can you maybe elaborate more on an answer, or point me to some references?

Comment: The keyword to search is Modern Theory of Polarisation. But it requires that you first understand Berry's phase. It is not an easy thing to learn about.